# Handling JSON Post request in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I want to create model entity in database using `POST` request. `GET` is working fine but `POST` is not being triggered. `views.py` is as follows:

```
    <code>
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets, generics
from server_app.serializers import DataSerializer
from server_app.models import DataModel
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from server_app.serializers import DataSerializer
import logging
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('This is GET request')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('This is POST request')

class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@csrf_exempt
def DataModel_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        logger.error("GET DATA SERVER")
        queryset = DataModel.objects.all()
        serializer_class = DataSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        #return HttpResponse(json.dumps(serializer_class.data),content_type="application/json")
        return JSONResponse(serializer_class.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        logger.error("POST DATA SERVER")
        json_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer_class = DataSerializer(data=json_data)
        if serializer_class.is_valid():
            serializer_class.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer_class.data, status=201)  
        return JSONResponse(serializer_class.errors, status=400)
    </code>
```

And following is my `urls.py`

```
<code>
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from rest_framework import routers
from django.contrib import admin
from server_app import views
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^getDataModel/$', views.DataModel_list),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
)
</code>
```

And `serializers.py`

```
<code>
from rest_framework import serializers
from server_app.models import  DataModel

class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DataModel
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'chapter', 'category', 'email', 'mantinada')
</code>
```

`models.py`

```
<code>
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class DataModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    chapter = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    mantinada = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

</code>
```

I have put `logger` in `GET` and `POST` requests. When I access url for `GET` I can see the results and logger consoles but for `POSt` request, i am not getting any logger information. Can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong at the `django server` end. I was calling wrongly from the `android-client` side because the `keys` in the android `json object` were different from `fields` in `models`. Correcting the keys have solved the problem.